# On a plane there are two identical circles that do not intersect. One straight line intersects circle 1 at...

Tags: geometry, circles, power-of-the-point

[image]

I've been given this question for homework, and I've made a bit of progress but I'm not sure what to do next. I called the intersection of the two lines $P$, and let $BP=x$ and $FP=y$. Thus, $PG=6-y$ and $PC=14-x$. I then used Power of a Point to get that $y=\frac{7x}{3}-\frac{40}{3}$, but I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: you linked the wrong problem.

Comment: oops. It's fixed now